# I want to continue to process image and store it when iOS App in background

Tags: ios, background, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I tried to use NSOperation and NSOperationQueue.
But As getting into background, NSOperation didn't work. it stopped.

Calling

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    findFQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    FindFeatureOperation *testOperation = [[FindFeatureOperation alloc] init];
    [findFQueue addOperation:testOperation];
}
```

NSOperation define

```
#import "FindFeatureOperation.h"

@implementation FindFeatureOperation
- (void)main
{
for (int i = 0; i < 999999 ; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Operation %d", i);
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
}
}
@end
```

Let me Know Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1 way: inside the op

to keep just running the operation:

```
- (main) {
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    for (int i = 0; i < 999999 ; i++) {
        NSLog(@"Operation %d", i);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    }

    [application endBackgroundTask];
}
```

## 2 way: using inside of applicationDidEnterBG:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)app {
    _bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
         // When Expired the limit time for background NSLog(@"Expired Background Task Limit Time");
             [app endBackgroundTask:_bgTask]; 
            _bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
         }];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
             [findFQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished]; 
            [app endBackgroundTask];
        }); 
}
```

Note: you can still be canceled if you use too much cpu / men / energy ... see the docs

Note 2: This can be written anywhere. I placed it in the OP but maybe in the VC is a better place... *I* don't think so but might be

Note 3: Read the docs! :: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Comment: Thank you for responding.
I have to use NSOperation.

Comment: I soleved by using waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished.
Thank you.

Comment: blocking on the main thread is not a valid way. IOS will kill you if you block 5s+

Comment: @nao0811ta which is why use NSOperaton ^^

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know 5s+ can block. So Do you know different way? 
Anyway, I don't mind blocking. background proccess is only a option. why i use nsoperation is my initial image proccessing takes much time.

Comment: blocking is bad I said: if you block 5s you get killed by the OS and it won't work. use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` like shown

Comment: I'll use beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler and NSOperation for continuing task in background.

Comment: - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{_bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        // When Expired the limit time for background
        NSLog(@"Expired Background Task Limit Time");
        [app endBackgroundTask:_bgTask];
        _bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(
                                             DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
     [findFQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
        });
}

Comment: your missing another endBackroundTask :: looking ok besides that :: - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)app {
 _bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
   // When Expired the limit time for background NSLog(@"Expired Background Task Limit Time");
    [app endBackgroundTask:_bgTask]; 
   _bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   }];
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [findFQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished]; 
   [app endBackgroundTask];
  }); 
}

Comment: OP works on foreground and background.
But Should I use beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler in OP?

Comment: I decided to use second way.